# What's the difference between "(:any)" and ":any" in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, routes

What's the difference between "(:any)" and ":any" in CodeIgniter URI routing rules? For example:

```
segment_1/segment_2/:any = my_controller/function/$1
```

And

```
segment_1/segment_2/(:any) = my_controller/function/$1
```

I don't see an explanation in the CI docs and wondered. :)

Comment: I would stick with parenthesis `(:any)` as this is what the documentation says:  [**Codeigniter Routing Wildcards**](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=route#wildcards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is difference between :any and (:any).

First `(:any)` replaced with $1 second `(:any)` replaced with $2 and so on

but `:any` does not have any effect.

As an example,Suppose you have a test controller with a function name myfunction takes an arguemnt $a like this

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function myfunction($a='')
    {

        echo $a;
    }
}
```

Hit this url `baseurl/test/asdf`

```
 $route['test/(:any)']='test/myfunction/$1';
 //$1== asdf
 //outputs  asdf

 $route['test/:any']='test/myfunction/$1';
//$1!=asdf
//outputs $1
```

Hope you understand the difference.